# How do you pass information to PHP with the onClick property?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I need to submit information to a new php page when a user clicks on an anchor tag.  I'm not sure how to do this, i know there is a POST method but that's for forms.  I could use the onClick property however, how do I load a php page and pass along data from the onClick property function?

Basically my page has a bunch of images on it.  I want the user to be able to click on one image, which will send them to a new php page which will enlarge it and give the user the ability to slide through other pictures like a slideshow.  I need to pass the image clicked to the new php document so it knows which image to enlarge.

Thanks,
-Matt

Answer (score 0):

Fill in the url with a image id.

`www.mydomain.com/images?i=`

Once on the php side just look at the value after `i` which would be your image index.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GET parameters in anchor tags:

```
<a href="image.php?id=123"><img src="..." /></a>
```

And fetch the GET parameter in your PHP file:

```
$imageID = $_GET['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach you may consider is using JQuery/Javascript to make an AJAX request to fetch the next image and have an overlayed `<div>`  over the page, displaying the images.

I'm sure the approaches from the other answers would work as well! An advantage of using the $_GET parameter is the ability to bookmark a page.